# Setting response header using interceptor?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy, interceptor

I'm writing jax-rs end points. For some set of end points (existing code), I want to set an extra response header which was actually generated in @AroundInvoke interceptor and set to HttpServletRequest attribute. In @AroundInvoke I'm able to access HttpServletRequest using @Inject. But it seems I cannot access HttpServletResponse in the same interceptor itself.

It seems I can do with PostProcessorInterceptor but again I'm confused with the following doc.

> The org.jboss.resteasy.spi.interception.PostProcessInterceptor runs after the JAX-RS method was invoked but before MessageBodyWriters are invoked. They can only be used on the server side. Use them if you need to set a response header **when there might not be any MessageBodyWriter invoked**.

I'm using resteasy, jackson. If I use PostProcessorInterceptor can I inject HttpServletResponse? Or Can I set new http header there some how?

Any code example/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: what javaee version are you working with?

Comment: I'm not sure...since it's preconfigured. Is there any easy way I can look up in eclipse? We are using wildfly 8.0, I guess it is java ee 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With JaxRS 2 (which comes with javaEE 7) you can use a `ContainerResponseFilter` [see also](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9580)

```
public class PoweredByResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Inject
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {
            String name = "X-My-Header";
            String value = "";// some data from request
            responseContext.getHeaders().add(name, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: PostProcessorInterceptor is deprecated right and now this should be used in place of that?

Comment: Could you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731511/how-to-use-the-same-containerrequestfilter-for-multiple-projects?

Comment: @pinkpanther when you want to modify headers filters are more preferable than interceptors.

Comment: @mkrakhin thanks..I was just curious what is the official replacement for the deprecated PostProcessorInterceptor....I'm using ContainerResponseFilter only in this case.